# Make the text go bold after button press

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a form in C# that has some buttons.  I want that when the button is pressed, make the text bold.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // string str = @"C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe";
            // string str = @"C:\windows\system32\winamp.exe";
            string str = @"C:\priority\bin.95\WINMENU.exe";
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
            process.Start(); 
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // string str = @"C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe";
            // string str = @"C:\windows\system32\winamp.exe";
            string str = @"C:\Program Files\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe";
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
            process.Start(); 
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // string str = @"C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe";
            // string str = @"C:\windows\system32\winamp.exe";
            string str = @"C:\Program Files\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe";
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
            process.Start(); 
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // string str = @"C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe";
            // string str = @"C:\windows\system32\winamp.exe";
            string str = @"C:\Windows\system32\mstsc.exe";
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
            process.Start();
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // string str = @"C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe";
            // string str = @"C:\windows\system32\winamp.exe";
            string str = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\winword.exe";
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
            process.Start();

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

what should I do now ?

Comment: Where is the text? Button text?

Comment: Please give us more info about your problem (what kind of form, what control, etc)

Answer (score 3):

Use the Click event for the button, something like this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = ((Button)sender);
        b.Font = new Font(b.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

@hyprsleepy - i dont think that your answer can work because the property Button.Font.Bold is read only so you can only read the value to see what it is currently set as.

@asher - where you have these events:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // string str = @"C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe";
    // string str = @"C:\windows\system32\winamp.exe";
    string str = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\winword.exe";
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
    process.Start();

}
```

use similar syntax to this:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // string str = @"C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe";
    // string str = @"C:\windows\system32\winamp.exe";
    string str = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\winword.exe";
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
    process.Start();

    Button b = ((Button)sender);
    b.Font = new Font(b.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

}
```

Comment: Yeah, i thought it was - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.bold.aspx

Comment: You are right Andy, I didn't double check that.  I usually just use CSS to do styling and leave that out of the code behind as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
```